# File operations std::remove and std::rename report "No such file or directory" in paths with spaces, even when escaped

Tags: c++, string

I would like to use the C++ functions `std::remove` and `std::rename` in my code (Linux based OS), but I get `No such file or directory` errors when I attempt this.  I suspect it has to do with the spaces in the path.

My original path looks like:

```
std::string str = "path/to my/file";
std::remove(str.c_str());
```

Naturally, when I attempt to use this with `ls`, it fails as it requires the space to be escaped.  I wrote a function to find and replace spaces in a string with escaped spaces.  The string above turns into `path/to\ my/file` when passed through this function.  So my work looks like:

```
std::string space_space(std::string instring) {
    std::string outstring;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(instring.c_str()); i++) {
        if (instring.c_str()[i] == ' ') {
            outstring += '\\';
            outstring += ' ';
        } else {
            outstring += instring.c_str()[i];
        }
    }
    return outstring;
}

std::string str = "path/to my/file"
std::remove(space_space(str).c_str());
```

Yet my `errno` on the function still returns "No such file or directory".  Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: In your `space_space()` function, `strlen(instring.c_str())` should be `instring.size()`, and `instring.c_str()[i]` should be `instring[i]`.  That said, your function is useless, because you don't actually need to escape spaces with ```\``` to begin with. That is not the real issue here.

Comment: If you can use C++17 or later, consider using [`std::filesystem::remove()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/remove) and [`std::filesystem::rename()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/rename) instead.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(instring.c_str()); i++)` -- Not only should that be `instring.size()` instead of `strlen`, you are calling `strlen` on each iteration of the loop.  You've created an `O(n^2)` loop for no reason.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am using C++17.

Comment: @RemyLebeau @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for the critique of the for loop, I'll fix that.  But in the meantime, why does it work?  Testing returns ``in: /path/to my/file
out: /path/to\ my/file``

Comment: @WesH we didn't say the function was *wrong*. The *logic* is fine, but your *implementation* is *inefficient* (another efficiency boost would be to use a `std::ostringstream` to collect the output instead of using a `std::string`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau and @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for the fix suggestions, I have applied them in my code.  I also realized that I only need the ``space_space`` function for preparing strings for ``system`` calls, while commands like ``remove`` assume quoted input, protecting the space.